# Calling a c# console application from Azure Data Factory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-batch

I have a c# console application that runs on an Azure VM - the application runs OK and does what it needs to. The application connects to an Azure storage account downloads a file of MAC addresses and creates an snmp trap for each MAC address which it sends to a Azure Load Balancer - this all works fine.

Is there a way I can call, monitor a c# console application from an ADF pipeline and run it as a server-less application on Azure - maybe using Azure Functions or Azure Batch or Azure other? Can you recommend the best Azure Service/Technology to use?

The Azure server-less solution will need to be able to connect to an Azure Storage Account and Key Vault so permissions is something I need advice on ?

NB: this c# application is **not** a big data application or require massive parallel processing.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem.

The c# console application can be run via Azure Batch on a node. A node is a VM running in Azure.

The Az data factory has a component that can call a Azure Batch which runs the c# console app.